Strawberry Shake client scaffolded differently depending on platform
I am running an ASP.NET Web API. Data access is done with Entity Framework (both NET8). ChilliCream's Hot Chocolate is used to integrate with that data model and expose it via GraphQL. On the client side there is a Blazor WASM project which uses Strawberry Shake (also ChilliCream) to scaffold the C# GrpahQL client.
I'm usually developing on Windows 11 and the setup works well. However, when switching over to Ubuntu 24.04 and dotnet run'ing the project, I can see that in the client, the methods' return types partly differ from those on Windows.
This also causes build errors since I am using the type names in function definitions downstream in the client app: error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'TypeCurrentlyScaffoldedOnLinux' to 'SameTypeAlreadyUsedInCodeFromWindows'
In the client app, it is my understanding that Strawberry Shake gets the schema.graphl file via introspection from the server and subsequently builds the strongly-typed C# client. I have diff'ed the schema.files in the same project on Windows and Linux and they are identical.
Still, let's have a look at an example. Here's a fragment I am using in one of the queries I want the client to build, this translates to an interface ISearchData.
fragment SearchData on Search {
    id
    droneId
    rescues {
        ... RescueData // <------ let's focus here
    }
    // abbreviated for clarity
}

On Windows the interface is defined as
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("StrawberryShake", "13.9.0.0")]
public partial interface ISearchData
{
    public global::System.Int32 Id { get; }
    public global::System.Int32 DroneId { get; }
    public global::System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<global::KitzUAV.App.IGetMission_Searches_Rescues> Rescues { get; }

    /// abbreviated for clarity
}

On Linux the interface is defined as
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("StrawberryShake", "13.9.0.0")]
public partial interface ISearchData
{
    public global::System.Int32 Id { get; }
    public global::System.Int32 DroneId { get; }
    public global::System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<global::KitzUAV.App.IAddSearchResuce_AddSearchRescue_Rescues> Rescues { get; }
    
    /// abbreviated for clarity
}

So this gives an error when building on Linux, the literal error message is:
error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IGrouping<KitzUAV.App.IAddSearchResuce_AddSearchRescue_Rescues_Box, KitzUAV.App.IAddSearchResuce_AddSearchRescue_Rescues>' to 'System.Linq.IGrouping<KitzUAV.App.IGetMission_Searches_Rescues_Box, KitzUAV.App.IGetMission_Searches_Rescues>'
Does someone know what's going on here?
Here's my env on both platforms:
dotnet --info on Windows11
.NET SDK:
 Version:           8.0.105
 Commit:            eae90abaaf
 Workload version:  8.0.100-manifests.bd5eea61

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.22631
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.105\

.NET workloads installed:
 Workload version: 8.0.100-manifests.bd5eea61
 [wasm-tools-net6]
   Installation Source: SDK 8.0.100
   Manifest Version:    8.0.5/8.0.100
   Manifest Path:       C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk-manifests\8.0.100\microsoft.net.workload.mono.toolchain.net6\8.0.5\WorkloadManifest.json
   Install Type:              Msi


Host:
  Version:      8.0.5
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       087e15321b

.NET SDKs installed:
  6.0.422 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  7.0.409 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  8.0.105 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.19 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.19 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 7.0.19 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 8.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

Other architectures found:
  None

Environment variables:
  Not set

global.json file:
  Not found

Learn more:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/info

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/download


dotnet --info on Ubuntu LTS
.NET SDK:
 Version:           8.0.300
 Commit:            326f6e68b2
 Workload version:  8.0.300-manifests.c1c70047
 MSBuild version:   17.10.4+10fbfbf2e

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  24.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         linux-x64
 Base Path:   /snap/dotnet-sdk/245/sdk/8.0.300/

.NET workloads installed:
There are no installed workloads to display.

Host:
  Version:      8.0.5
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       087e15321b

.NET SDKs installed:
  8.0.300 [/snap/dotnet-sdk/245/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.5 [/snap/dotnet-sdk/245/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.5 [/snap/dotnet-sdk/245/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Other architectures found:
  None

Environment variables:
  Not set

global.json file:
  Not found

Learn more:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/info

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/download


PS: I upgraded the SDK to v 8.0.301 on Windows to make it more comparable. Same behaviour, though
